Transiesta issues: system coordinates of atoms does not coincide with the electrode coordinates found in systemlabel.TSHS
I am repeating results from the paper : 10.1103/PhysRevB.81.205437.
my transport device is described in the following image:

First, I do a calculation on the electrode. Here is the POSITION file.
NumberOfAtoms        16
NumberOfSpecies      1

%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
1  6 C-GGA
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel 
                        
LatticeConstant 1.00 Ang
%block LatticeVectors
16.5000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.0000000000 8.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.0000000000 0.0000000000 4.4029002190
%endblock LatticeVectors

AtomicCoordinatesFormat fractional
%block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
 2.112124264         4.000000000         1.566548892 1
 2.112124756         4.000000477         2.836387805 1
 3.265819564         3.999999285         0.716230216 1
 3.265823007         4.000000000         3.686702413 1
 4.516985759         4.000000000         1.471068833 1
 4.516986251         4.000000000         2.931851331 1
 5.768222764         4.000000000         0.729649875 1
 5.768224731         3.999999762         3.673258742 1
 7.021896824         4.000000477         1.471773860 1
 7.021897808         3.999999523         2.931120979 1
 8.273327082         4.000000000         0.730428974 1
 8.273328066         4.000000477         3.672457008 1
 9.524708658         3.999999523         1.485192862 1
 9.524706692         3.999999285         2.917682294 1
10.678370029         3.999999762         0.634907581 1
10.678371996         4.000000477         3.767961474 1
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies      
                                             

INPUT file:
SystemName    elec                                                                                                                     
SystemLabel   elec

%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
 1  0   0    0.0
  0   1   0    0.0
  0   0  45   0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack


xc.functional           GGA                      
xc.authors              PBE                      

MeshCutoff              300.00000000 Ry 
SolutionMethod          diagon                   
OccupationFunction      MP                       
ElectronicTemperature   300 K                    

SpinPolarized           F                        
FixSpin                 F                        

MaxSCFIterations        200                      
#DM.Tolerance           1.d-5                    
DM.NumberPulay          6                        
DM.NumberBroyden        0                        
DM.MixingWeight         0.1000000000             
DM.OccupancyTolerance   0.1000000000E-11         
DM.NumberKick           0                        
DM.KickMixingWeight     0.5000000000             
DM.Tolerance            0.1000000000E-03         

#UseSaveData             T                        

         

MD.NumCGsteps            0                      
MD.TypeOfRun            CG                       
MD.VariableCell         F                        
MD.MaxCGDispl           0.2000000000  Bohr       
MD.MaxForceTol          0.05 eV/Ang              
MD.MaxStressTol         0.0001 eV/Ang**3

Diag.ParallelOverK      T                        
                       
PAO.EnergyShift         50 meV                   
PAO.SplitNorm           0.1500000000             
PAO.BasisType           split                    
PAO.BasisSize           SZP          
                          



WriteMullikenPop        0      
WriteDenchar            T      
WriteKpoints            T      
WriteForces             T      
WriteDM                 T      
WriteXML                T      
WriteBands              F      
WriteKbands             F      
WriteEigenvalues        T      
WriteCoorStep           T      
WriteMDhistory          T      
WriteMDXmol             T      
WriteWaveFunctions      F      
WriteCoorXmol           T      

TS.HS.Save              true
TS.DE.Save              true

                                                                                                                               
%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
    1  6 C-GGA
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel 



BandLinesScale ReciprocalLatticeVectors
%block BandLines
1 0 0 0
50 0 0 0.5
%endblock Bandlines


%include POSITIONS.fdf


Then, I did transport calculation on the device. Here is the POSITION file.
NumberOfAtoms 112
NumberOfSpecies 1
LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang
%block LatticeVectors
16.5000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 0.0000000000 8.0000000000 0.0000000000
 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 30.8202991486
%endblock LatticeVectors

%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
    1  6 C-GGA
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel

AtomicCoordinatesFormat Ang
%block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
     2.112124264         4.000000000         1.566548820 1
     2.112124756         4.000000477         2.836387651 1
     3.265819564         3.999999285         0.716230112 1
     3.265823007         4.000000000         3.686702226 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000         1.471068801 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000         2.931851137 1
     5.768222764         4.000000000         0.729649810 1
     5.768224731         3.999999762         3.673258360 1
     7.021896824         4.000000477         1.471773648 1
     7.021897808         3.999999523         2.931120686 1
     8.273327082         4.000000000         0.730428942 1
     8.273328066         4.000000477         3.672456954 1
     9.524708658         3.999999523         1.485192830 1
     9.524706692         3.999999285         2.917682101 1
    10.678370029         3.999999762         0.634907532 1
    10.678371996         4.000000477         3.767961084 1
     2.112124264         4.000000000         5.969448321 1
     2.112124756         4.000000477         7.239287267 1
     3.265819564         3.999999285         5.119129843 1
     3.265823007         4.000000000         8.089602531 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000         5.873968532 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000         7.334750982 1
     5.768222764         4.000000000         5.132549828 1
     5.768224731         3.999999762         8.076158205 1
     7.021896824         4.000000477         5.874673494 1
     7.021897808         3.999999523         7.334020762 1
     8.273327082         4.000000000         5.133328730 1
     8.273328066         4.000000477         8.075356340 1
     9.524708658         3.999999523         5.888093020 1
     9.524706692         3.999999285         7.320581488 1
    10.678370029         3.999999762         5.037807148 1
    10.678371996         4.000000477         8.170860929 1
     2.112124264         4.000000000        10.372348397 1
     2.112124756         4.000000477        11.642186424 1
     3.265819564         3.999999285         9.522029918 1
     3.265823007         4.000000000        12.492502147 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        10.276868607 1 
     4.516985759         4.000000000        11.737650598 1
     5.768222764         4.000000000         9.535449444 1
     5.768224731         3.999999762        12.479057821 1
     7.021896824         4.000000477        10.277573110 1
     7.021897808         3.999999523        11.736921296 1
     8.273327082         4.000000000         9.536229264 1
     8.273328066         4.000000477        12.478256875 1
     9.524708658         3.999999523        10.290992635 1
     9.524706692         3.999999285        11.723481563 1
    10.678370029         3.999999762         9.440707223 1
    10.678371996         4.000000477        12.573760545 1
     2.112124264         4.000000000        14.775248013 1
     2.112124756         4.000000477        16.045086958 1
     3.265819564         3.999999285        13.924930452 1
     3.265823007         4.000000000        16.895401763 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        14.679768223 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        16.140550214 1
     5.768222764         4.000000000        13.938349060 1
     5.768224731         3.999999762        16.881958356 1
     7.021896824         4.000000477        14.680472725 1
     7.021897808         3.999999523        16.139819075 1
     8.273327082         4.000000000        13.939128880 1
     8.273328066         4.000000477        16.881155572 1 
     9.524708658         3.999999523        14.693892251 1
     9.524706692         3.999999285        16.126383016 1
    10.678370029         3.999999762        13.843607758 1
    10.678371996         4.000000477        16.976661080 1
     2.112124264         4.000000000        19.178148547 1
     2.112124756         4.000000477        20.447986574 1
     3.265819564         3.999999285        18.327828231 1
     3.265823007         4.000000000        21.298301379 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        19.082666921 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        20.543449830 1
     5.768222764         4.000000000        18.341249594 1
     5.768224731         3.999999762        21.284857971 1
     7.021896824         4.000000477        19.083374178 1
     7.021897808         3.999999523        20.542720528 1
     8.273327082         4.000000000        18.342028496 1
     8.273328066         4.000000477        21.284057025 1
     9.524708658         3.999999523        19.096791867 1
     9.524706692         3.999999285        20.529280795 1
    10.678370029         3.999999762        18.246506455 1
    10.678371996         4.000000477        21.379560696 1
     2.112124264         4.000000000        23.581048163 1
     2.112124756         4.000000477        24.850886190 1
     3.265819564         3.999999285        22.730729684 1
     3.265823007         4.000000000        25.701200995 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        23.485568374 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        24.946351283 1
     5.768222764         4.000000000        22.744149210 1
     5.768224731         3.999999762        25.687757587 1
     7.021896824         4.000000477        23.486273794 1
     7.021897808         3.999999523        24.945620144 1
     8.273327082         4.000000000        22.744928112 1
     8.273328066         4.000000477        25.686954804 1
     9.524708658         3.999999523        23.499691483 1
     9.524706692         3.999999285        24.932182248 1
    10.678370029         3.999999762        22.649407908 1
    10.678371996         4.000000477        25.782460312 1 
     2.112124264         4.000000000        27.983949616 1
     2.112124756         4.000000477        29.253787643 1
     3.265819564         3.999999285        27.133629300 1
     3.265823007         4.000000000        30.104102448 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        27.888469827 1
     4.516985759         4.000000000        29.349250899 1
     5.768222764         4.000000000        27.147048826 1
     5.768224731         3.999999762        30.090657203 1
     7.021896824         4.000000477        27.889173410 1
     7.021897808         3.999999523        29.348519760 1
     8.273327082         4.000000000        27.147827728 1
     8.273328066         4.000000477        30.089856257 1
     9.524708658         3.999999523        27.902592936 1
     9.524706692         3.999999285        29.335081864 1
    10.678370029         3.999999762        27.052305687 1
    10.678371996         4.000000477        30.185361765 1
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies   

Here is the script to do current calculation on each voltage.
cp ../step-1-electrodes/elec.TSHS   .  # copy TSHS file from step-1

mkdir cont   # read the comment at the end of this script.

for i in `seq -w 0.0 0.1 1.8`  
do


cp -r cont $i
cd $i
cp ../*.psf .
cp ../elec.TSHS .
cp ../POSITIONS.fdf .

cat > INPUT.fdf <<EOF
SystemName    scat                                                                                                                     
SystemLabel   scat

%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
  1   0   0    0.0
  0   1   0    0.0
  0   0   45    0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack


xc.functional           GGA                     
xc.authors              PBE                     

MeshCutoff              300.00000000 Ry 
SolutionMethod Transiesta                       
OccupationFunction      MP                      
ElectronicTemperature   300 K                   

SpinPolarized           F                       
FixSpin                 F                       

MaxSCFIterations        1000                    
#DM.Tolerance           1.d-5                   
DM.NumberPulay          6                       
DM.NumberBroyden        0                       
DM.MixingWeight         0.1000000000            
DM.OccupancyTolerance   0.1000000000E-11        
DM.NumberKick           0                       
DM.KickMixingWeight     0.5000000000            
DM.Tolerance            0.1000000000E-03        

#UseSaveData             T                       
                  
MD.NumCGsteps           0                        
MD.TypeOfRun            CG                       
MD.VariableCell         F                        
MD.MaxCGDispl           0.2000000000  Bohr       
MD.MaxForceTol          0.05 eV/Ang              
MD.MaxStressTol         0.0001 eV/Ang**3        


Diag.ParallelOverK      F                                                
PAO.EnergyShift         50 meV                    
PAO.SplitNorm           0.1500000000              
PAO.BasisType           split                     
PAO.BasisSize           SZP          
                          

WriteMullikenPop                0
WriteBands                      F
SaveRho                         F
SaveElectrostaticPotential      F
SaveTotalPotential              F
WriteCoorXmol                   T


                                                                                                                               
%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
    1  6 C-GGA
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel 

%include POSITIONS.fdf


# Transiesta information
SolutionMethod Transiesta 
# GENGF OPTIONS
TS.ComplexContour.Emin        -28 eV 
TS.ComplexContour.NPoles       16
TS.ComplexContour.NCircle      16
TS.ComplexContour.NLine        10 
# BIAS OPTIONS
TS.biasContour.NumPoints       10

%block TS.Atoms.Buffer
atom [ 17 -- 32 ]
atom [ 81 -- 96 ]
%endblock


# TS OPTIONS
TS.Voltage $i  eV

# TBT OPTIONS
TS.TBT.Emin -3 eV
TS.TBT.Emax +3 eV
TS.TBT.NPoints 500
TS.TBT.NEigen 3
TS.TBT.Eta        0.000001 Ry

# Write electrode hamiltonian
TS.SaveHS   .true.
TS.SaveLead .true.
#TS.Elecs.Neglect.Principal true

# ---------------------------------------------------
# Here we first list and then define all electrodes that are used
# in our system. For each electrode we define:
#   - HS: Path to the hamiltonian of the bulk electrode (previously computed).
#   - chemical-potential: The name of the chemical potential to use for this
#     electrode, as defined previously on this same file.
#   - semi-inf-direction: The direction in which we will extend the electrode
#     infinitely.
#   - electrode-position: First (if positive) or last (if negative) atom index
#     of the electrode in our full system. All electrode atoms must appear
#     consecutively in the system!
%block TS.Elecs
  Left
  Right
%endblock TS.Elecs

%block TS.Elec.Left
  HS ./elec.TSHS
  chemical-potential Left
  semi-inf-direction -a3
  electrode-position 1
%endblock
%block TS.Elec.Right
  HS ./elec.TSHS
  chemical-potential Right
  semi-inf-direction +a3
  electrode-position end -1
%endblock

==================================================
==================================================

EOF

mpirun --map-by ppr:12:node -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 siesta INPUT.fdf > out

cd ..
rm -rf cont 
mkdir cont

cp  ./$i/scat.TSDE ./$i/scat.TSHS ./$i/scat.DM  cont  # copy these files for continuation of the next bias step.


done

The program stopped on each voltage calculation and here is the part of output file on 0.0 voltage.
superc: Internal auxiliary supercell:     1 x     1 x     3  =       3
superc: Number of atoms, orbitals, and projectors:    336   3024   5376

 Kpoints in:            1 . Kpoints trimmed:            1

siesta: transiesta k-grid: Number of k-points = 1
siesta: transiesta k-points from Monkhorst-Pack grid
siesta: transiesta k-cutoff (effective) =     4.000 Ang
siesta: transiesta k-point supercell and displacements
siesta: k-grid:     1     0     0      0.000
siesta: k-grid:     0     1     0      0.000
siesta: k-grid:     0     0     1      0.000
error-ELEC: >> Left
error-ELEC:   Electrode cell pivoting: E1, E2, E3   = A1, A2, A3
error-ELEC:   GF file                               = scat.TSGFLeft
error-ELEC:   GF file reuse if found                =    T
error-ELEC:   Electrode TSHS file                   = ./elec.TSHS
error-ELEC:   # atoms in electrode used / total     = 16 / 16
error-ELEC:   Electrode Bloch unity [E1 x E2 x E3]  = 1 x 1 x 1
error-ELEC:   Position in geometry                  = 1 -- 16
error-ELEC:   Semi-infinite direction for electrode = negative wrt. E3
error-ELEC:   Chemical shift                        =    0.000000 eV
error-ELEC:   Electronic temperature                =  300.000000 K
error-ELEC:   Gamma-only electrode                  =    F
error-ELEC:   Bulk H, S in electrode region         =    T
error-ELEC:   Initial DM for electrodes             = diagon
error-ELEC:   Cross-terms are updated
error-ELEC:   Manual delta-Ef shift                 =    0.000000 eV
error-ELEC:   Electrode self-energy imaginary Eta   =  0.1000E-02 eV
error-ELEC:   Electrode self-energy accuracy        =  0.1000E-12 eV
error-ELEC:   Electrode inter-layer distance (semi-i=    9.3916 Ang
error-ELEC:   Hartree potential box:
error-ELEC:     box origo                           = { -0.18548E+01, -0.59500E-07,  0.11839E-05} Ang
error-ELEC:     box v1                              = {  0.16500E+02,  0.00000E+00,  0.00000E+00} Ang
error-ELEC:     box v2                              = {  0.00000E+00,  0.80000E+01,  0.00000E+00} Ang
error-ELEC:     box v3                              = {  0.00000E+00,  0.00000E+00,  0.44029E+01} Ang

The electrode coordinates does not overlap within the required accuracy: .10000E-02 Ang
The maximal offset repeating vector is [Ang]:  132.8     0.3339E-05  7.491    
The maximal offset tiling vector is    [Ang]:  132.8     0.3339E-05  7.491    
The system coordinates of atoms 1 to 16 does not coincide with the electrode coordinates found in: ./elec.TSHS
This is a requirement to place the self-energy terms correctly.
To ensure the electrode coordinates conform with the system coordinates you can take the following list of coordinates
and replace atoms 1 to 16 in your system AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies block
NOTICE: The below listed coordinates are tiled as that provides the best performance
NOTICE: The listed coordinates are already arranged with respect to atom 1 in your system AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies block
NOTICE: You have to add the correct species label for the atoms
NOTICE: You can possibly do this by using this awk-command on this output:
        awk '{print $5,$6,$7,1}' <OUT-file>

                                                           DEVICE                            EXPANDED ELECTRODE (expected DEVICE atomic coordinates)
                X [Ang]              Y [Ang]              Z [Ang]       |dXA| [Ang]                X [Ang]              Y [Ang]              Z [Ang]
           2.1121242640         4.0000000000         1.5665488200          0.000000           2.1121242640         4.0000000000         1.5665488200
           2.1121247560         4.0000004770         2.8363876510          4.321135           2.1121323820         4.0000038160         7.1575228481
           3.2658195640         3.9999992850         0.7162301120         18.114869          21.1480967140         3.9999942800        -2.1773194648
           3.2658230070         4.0000000000         3.6867022260         19.282874          21.1481535235         4.0000000000        10.9013732219
           4.5169857590         4.0000000000         1.4710688010         37.276769          41.7923389315         4.0000000000         1.1461596473
           4.5169857590         4.0000000000         2.9318511370         37.563783          41.7923470495         4.0000000000         7.5778392277
           5.7682227640         4.0000000000         0.7296498100         56.741041          62.4377495140         4.0000000000        -2.1182340452
           5.7682247310         3.9999997620         3.6732583600         57.121206          62.4377819695         3.9999980960        10.8421820799
           7.0218968240         4.0000004770         1.4717736480         76.102158          83.1233715040         4.0000038160         1.1492638109
           7.0218978080         3.9999995230         2.9311206860         76.243025          83.1233877400         3.9999961840         7.5746235607
           8.2733270820         4.0000000000         0.7304289420         95.541019         103.7719707610         4.0000000000        -2.1148037501
           8.2733280660         4.0000004770         3.6724569540         95.767156         103.7719869970         4.0000038160        10.8386521251
           9.5247086580         3.9999995230         1.4851928300        114.895392         124.4197667650         3.9999961840         1.2083463377
           9.5247066920         3.9999992850         2.9176821010        114.986986         124.4197343260         3.9999942800         7.5154543716
          10.6783700290         3.9999997620         0.6349075320        132.814652         143.4551793865         3.9999980960        -2.5353749122
          10.6783719960         4.0000004770         3.7679610840        132.987996         143.4552118420         4.0000038160        11.2591487594
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    0
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    2
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    8
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:   11
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:   10
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    6
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    7
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    5
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    9
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    1
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    3
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    4


I did not relax the electrode and device and I try to keep the atomic coordinates of electrode consecutive with those in the device. I did not figure out why this program still abort.
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

There are multiple things wrong in your input...

You seem to be using TS.Atoms.Buffer, but as far as I can see from your input, you don't want to use it... Why do you have it? What do you think it does?
A buffer atom is completely removed from the transiesta calculation... Do you want that?

The error happens because the relative coordinates of the electrode calculation and the electrode in the device calculation are not commensurate.
Did you read the error message?



The electrode coordinates does not overlap within the required
accuracy: .10000E-02 Ang The maximal offset repeating vector is [Ang]:
132.8     0.3339E-05  7.491     The maximal offset tiling vector is    [Ang]:  132.8     0.3339E-05  7.491     The system coordinates of
atoms 1 to 16 does not coincide with the electrode coordinates found
in: ./elec.TSHS This is a requirement to place the self-energy terms
correctly. To ensure the electrode coordinates conform with the system
coordinates you can take the following list of coordinates and replace
atoms 1 to 16 in your system AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies block
NOTICE: The below listed coordinates are tiled as that provides the
best performance NOTICE: The listed coordinates are already arranged
with respect to atom 1 in your system
AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies block NOTICE: You have to add the
correct species label for the atoms NOTICE: You can possibly do this
by using this awk-command on this output:
        awk '{print $5,$6,$7,1}' <OUT-file>



Sir, I have commented on TS.Atoms.Buffer and modified the POSITIONS.fdf file as suggested by error message. I have updated the new POSITIONS.fdf of device and new error message in the question.

As suggested by error message, I add ```
%block AtomicCoordinatesOrigin
0.0000        0.0000        7.2312
-0.0000       -0.0000      -11.5521
-0.0000       -0.0000      -18.7833
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesOrigin
     -0.0000       -0.0000      -11.5521 is included by previous error message,-0.0000       -0.0000      -18.7833 is included by last error message, but -0.0000       -0.0000      -18.7833 can not be recognized as suggested by the last error message

@xinbiaowang for a new error message, please post a new question.
